# Does F# treat parameter matching differently when there is only one input parameter?

Tags: f#, parameters

The function matching is based on the definition of the file in F#:

```
let f2 x y = x + y
let value5 = f2 10 20
let value = f2(10, 20) <-- Error

let f3 (x, y) = x + y
let value6 = f3(10, 20)
let value = f3 10 20 <-- Error
```

However, I can use in both ways with one parameter with F#:

```
let f n = n + 10
let value3 = f 10
let value4 = f(10)
```

Why is this? Does F# treat parameter matching differently when there is only one input parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As ashays correctly explains, the two ways of declaring functions are different. You can see that by looking at the type signature. Here is an F# interactive session:

```
> let f1 (x, y) = x + y;;  
val f1 : int * int -> int

> let f2 x y = x + y;;
val f2 : int -> int -> int
```

The first function takes a tuple of type `int * int` and returns `int`. When calling it, you need to specify the tuple (which is just a single value):

```
// Using tuple directly as the argument
f1 (1, 2)

// .. or by declaring tuple value first
let tup = (1, 2)
f1 tup
```

The type of the second function is `int -> int -> int`, which is the same thing as `int -> (int -> int)`. This means that it is a function that takes `int` and returns a function that takes `int` and returns `int`. This form is called *curried* form and it allows you to use *partial function application* as demonstrated by ashays. In fact, the call:

```
f2 1 2

// Could be written as:
(f2 1) 2
```

Comment: Also, tuple literals in F# are created by the comma, not the parenthesis. In other words, `let foo = (x, y)` is the same as `let foo = x, y` and `f 10` is the same as `f(10)` - creating a group of one element doesn't change how you call the method.

Answer (score 1):

My suspection is that this has something to do with tuples and currying.  Basically, a tuple of one item becomes a singular item again, however in our other two cases we have the following:

The first case (`f2`) is actually a function that takes a single value (`x`) and returns a value that takes another single function.  Here we can see the use of currying from `f2` to `add10`

```
let add10 = f2 10     
let myVal = add10 20
```

We get an error with the tuple because we have not defined it in such a way as to receive a tuple.  In the second example, we have a similar issue, where we defined the function to take a tuple of two values, and it knows how to process those values, but we have passed it two values now instead of the one (a tuple) that it was expecting, and thus we receive an error.

Once again, in the last case, we have a tuple of a single item and so `f x` and `f(x)` are effectively the same thing.

I could be wrong in my reasoning, but I believe that's why you're getting your errors.